# Which authentication gem would you use in Rails 3 to integrate with as many third party authentication providers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

We need to have basic authentication in our Rails 3 app but the requirements are to also integrate with providers such as facebook, linked in, google apps, twitter, etc.

We are looking at:

- Clearance
- Divise
- AuthLogic
- ... and others.

Any advice on which one to use that provides most of what we need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is the current top dog, as it sets up sensible defaults, and makes it remarkably easy to override parts of the authentication system without affecting the rest.

It also has a branch and instructions to easily support OmniAuth for OAuth/OpenID authentication: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Answer (score 2):

OmniAuth is great for plugging in to third party authentication:

### Code: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1
and
http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2
The above railscasts are great resources for a simple overview of using OmniAuth.

Comment: Both of those Railscasts are Devise-specific as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with either of these gems but I came across this blog post that had some high level points comparing Devise and Authlogic.  http://www.quora.com/Ruby-on-Rails/How-should-I-choose-an-authentication-gem

This one persuaded me to start with Authlogic:

> When a user logs in I like to set a cookie that has the username so I can access it from JavaScript. I know how to do this with Authlogic: add a line of code to UserSessionsController#create.  How do I do it with Devise? I can't see how. (I don't want to do it on every page request.  Just when they authenticate.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a shot to [Sorcery gem](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) which nicely handle third party authentification.
I found it easy to learn and to implement, and it's well documented too.
I don't try the other gems but this one is growing very fast right now, despite the fact that it's not an very old project

Good luck!!!